# How to stop and resume a Thread in a safe way in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a heartbeat object that will keep sending request, 
but it may pause and resume....But I can stop it, but can't resume back....

Here is the HeartBeat Object:

```
public void startBeating() {
    heartBeatTask = new HeartBeatTask(monitorInterval);
    heartBeatTaskThread = new Thread(heartBeatTask);
}

public void stopBeating() {
    heartBeatTask.setKeepHeartBeat(false);
}

public void beating() {
    heartBeatTask.setKeepHeartBeat(true);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    this.startBeating();
    this.beating();
    heartBeatTaskThread.start();
}
```

And the heartBeatTask as follow:

```
public HeartBeatTask(long aHeartBeatInterval){
    this.heartBeatInterval = aHeartBeatInterval;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(isKeepHeartBeat()){
        System.out.println("beating");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(this.heartBeatInterval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Both object is a runnable object in java, what's going wrong that I can't resume the beating:

How I resume the beating:

```
    this.beating();
```

How I stop bearing:

```
    this.stopBeating();
```

Comment: Why don't you try `wait` and `notify` instead??

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use wait() and notify()

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuntely, you have more than just a beating/non beating state.

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        HeartBeat hb = new HeartBeat();
        Thread t = new Thread(hb);
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        hb.setPaused(true);
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        hb.setPaused(false);
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        hb.stopBeating();
        t.join(); // make sure the thread terminates correctly;
        System.out.println("Patient is dead.");
    }
}

class HeartBeat implements Runnable
{
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private volatile boolean paused = false;
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public void run()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            if(paused)
            {
                synchronized (lock)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while (paused)
                        {
                            lock.wait();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                }
                System.out.println("Beat");
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopBeating()
    {
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            running = false;
            paused = false;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void setPaused(boolean paused)
    {
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            this.paused = paused;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to be able to pause the thread, in this case I am just using the Object.wait() and Object.notify().

Other options could include using a Thread pool and re-adding this task to the pool when you want to start the job again. You just need to make sure that you don't add the task twice as you'd be beating twice as often as necessary.

Since you are writing something that gets executed every xxxx seconds, you might want to check out the `ScheduledExecutorService`. Pausing/stopping would involve `cancel`ing the task, resuming would be a matter of re-adding the task.

Comment: Your second suggestion of using an executor service seems like a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is to let the thread die on stop and create a new thread on resume.  Use a thread pool if you do this (optional and not necessary in a small standalone app).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Here's how your example would play out:

```
public void startBeating() {
    semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    heartBeatTask = new HeartBeatTask(monitorInterval, semaphore);
    heartBeatTaskThread = new Thread(heartBeatTask);
}

public void stopBeating() {
    try { 
        semaphore.aquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

public void beating() {
    semaphore.release();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    this.startBeating();
    this.beating();
    heartBeatTaskThread.start();
}

public HeartBeatTask(long aHeartBeatInterval, Semaphore semaphore){
    this.heartBeatInterval = aHeartBeatInterval;
    this.semaphore = semaphore;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(isKeepHeartBeat()){
        System.out.println("beating");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(this.heartBeatInterval);
            semaphore.acquire(); // we acquire then immediately release
            semaphore.release(); // so that if the other thread has
                                 // already acquired it we'll block (so not beat).
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst an interesting solution, the problems that it brings up are that calling code would block on the stopBeating() call until another thread calls beating(). In this case, if 2 threads are required, if they both called stopBeating(), then you would need to call beating() twice.

Comment: Yeah, you'd want a flag to guard against that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code is that, in your stop method, you set "isKeepHeartBeat" as false, then your thread finished, but not paused.

So you need to use semaphore or wait() to let your thread to wait there, but not finished.